# UITabBarController apears after changing window rootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm developing an app, where you have LoginVC presented as rootVC and launch. After successful login, I change window rootVC to TabBarVC I created. It works fine. Problem is that when I logout and change window rootVC to LoginVC it appears for a second and then it is covered by distorted TabBarVC with first view selected. My TabBarVC consists of 3 VCs that are embedded in NavCon. I also use SideMenu as second navigation to tabbar. How can I prevent overlapping LoginVC by TabBarVC after logout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough info about your code, but I guess your problem happens because of animations interference, try to disable animation when you want to change window from rootVC to LoginVC , i.e use: `animated: false` to see if helps or not :S

Comment: I didn't set any animations. Just using
delegate.window.rootViewController = LoginVC
or
delegate.window.rootViewController = TabBarVC
where delegate is AppDelegate

Comment: Got it! Problem was with dismissing SideMenu! Thanks!